# Check if its a character

Tags: java, string, char, keyevent

After getting an action from the KeyListener, using the event.getKeyCode() and later on the KeyEvent.getKeyText(keyCode), how would i check if the outcome of .getKeyText(keyCode) is a single character like 'a' and not a whole word like "Space" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
KeyEvent.getKeyText(keyCode).length == 1
```

Comment: Genius, but what about "space"?

Comment: Also, the backtick, ~_-+=[]{};':"\|,./<>? and all numpad keys don't register a character. Otherwise, very nice method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use getKeyChar() of the KeyEvent, and then'll you be certain that what you get back is a single char.

E.g. something like this:

```
   public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        keyChar = e.getKeyChar();
        ...
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
if ((event.keyCode > 64 && event.keyCode < 91) || (event.keyCode > 96 && event.keyCode < 123) || event.keyCode == 8)
{
  if(KeyEvent.getKeyText(keyCode).length == 1)
  {
    //Only one character is pressed.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for everything except the delete key and numpad keys...

```
event.getKeyChar() != '\uFFFF'
```

Because any Java outputs that character for non-renderable keys, it works quite consistently.

To fix the delete key problem...

```
event.getKeyChar() != '\uFFFF' && event.getKeyCode() != KeyEvent.VK_DELETE
```

It will return `true` if the key is printable, and `false` if not.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in SWT, in SWT I have KeyEvent.character